Firestore rules strange behavior
I'm building a web app with Firebase Firestore and trying to create a permission system.
My data is structured as follows:

projects (collection)

[projectId] (document)

allowRead (value)
someData (value)
users (collection)

[userId] (document)

permission (value)









Every user should only be able to request a project when they are listed in users and have the needed permission.
Here are my Firestore rules:
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /projects {
allow read: if true;
// Regeln für die Projekte
match /{projectId} {
allow read:  if isUserAuthorized('read');
allow write: if isUserAuthorized('write');

// Regeln für alle Unterdokumente
match /{document=**} {
 allow read: if isUserAuthorized('read');
 allow write: if isUserAuthorized('write');
}
        
function isUserAuthorized(permission) {
  return (
     // Überprüfen, ob der Nutzer authentifiziert ist und die Berechtigung hat
     request.auth != null &&
     (
       get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(projectId)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.permission == permission ||
       get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(projectId)/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.permission == 'write'
     )
   ) || (
     // Überprüfen, ob eine allgemeine Berechtigung zum Lesen der Ressource vorliegt
     permission == 'read' &&
     get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(projectId)).data.allowRead == true
   );
  }
 }
}

}
}

The problem is that when I request the collection "/projects", it seems unable to check the projectId and im getting an empty array. I'm not sure, but the projectId seems to not be defined. When I request "/projects/someId/users", the permission check work fine.

Rules don't do anyting on their own, but only become active then you run code against them. Please edit your question to include the minimal code that doesn't work as expected. Make sure that in that code you prove that it meets the requirement of your rules, i.e. check and log the UID, log the document IDs, etc.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.
